# How to return DOM from Selenium after click

Tags: python, html, dom, selenium

I'd like to use Selenium to get the HTML of a page after a link has been clicked. Normally, I would just download the link I want to click, but in this case when the link is clicked it fires off some obfuscated Javascript, which loads data back into the DOM of the current page. It's pretty nasty.

So, here's what I expected to work. This loads the page, finds and clicks the link I need, then returns the DOM as text using `outerHTML` from JavaScript:

```
from selenium import webdriver

def get_html_after_click(i):
    '''Loads a page, then clicks an element, and returns the HTML'''
    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
    browser.get('http://www.sdjudicial.com/sc/scopinions.aspx')
    elem = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('igeb_ItemLabel')[i]
    elem.click()

    js = '''html = document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0];
            return html.outerHTML;'''
    html = browser.execute_script(js)

    browser.quit()

    return html
```

Except whenever I run this, the HTML I get back is the same as if I had done `browser.page_source` -- even though I've clicked the link and grabbed the DOM using JavaScript.

I'm new to Selenium. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are doing it really quickly.
After you click on the element, `wait` for an expected element that shows up because of the click and then do 
`browser.page_source`
or execute your java script

Comment: Yep. I had a wait in there already, but it wasn't enough. Thanks.

Comment: Notice that this is **not** the DOM but rather the HTML source.